# How can jquery function know AJAX is completed

Tags: jquery, ajax, getjson

I load image url contents for a div by getJSON, when it is done it will change a variable so I know AJAX is done

How other function know AJAX is done? Here is what I want:

User navigates to album div then it will check AJAX is done or not. If AJAX is not done, a loading image is showed, but when AJAX is completed, how can it knows AJAX is completed to stop showing loading image?

My thoughts:

1/ Continuously checking AJAX status variable by using while loop will freeze everything and actually does not work.

2/ I can not put all the navigation code in callback function because I want user can do freely while AJAX is loading. Putting it all in callback function creates a mess of code

How can this problem is solved?

Answer (score 3):

You should never "check" whether AJAX is completed by polling a variable, you should register  a callback that will be *automatically* invoked when it is done, preferably using jQuery's ["deferred objects"](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), e.g.

```
$.getJSON(...).done(function(data) {
    // my ajax is finished!
});
```

Ultimately you don't have to put all of your code *in* the callback, but you need to ensure that it ends up called *by* the callback.

Comment: I still cant get the idea. As I already said, if I put navigation code in callback function then it will be freeze until that. What I need is method for navigation code to know AJAX is completed or not

Comment: @user2174870 nothing should "freeze" with this code, unless you're using a "busy loop" somewhere else.  Your navigation code should never be running _continuously_ - JS code should only ever run in response to some sort of event, and then only briefly.  The browser would then sit idle until the next event is received.

Comment: @user2174870 p.s. you said in the question that "continuously checking status ... will freeze everything" - that's right.  Using callbacks is the way to _prevent_ freezing, but then it's just a case of structuring your code correctly so as not to "create a mess of code".  Using deferred objects can significantly improve async code because it helps eliminate deep nesting.

Answer (score 2):

in the ajax call there is one extension called "success: function(data)" the data contains whatever you got from the request.

```
   $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   dataType="json",
   url:url,
   data:{id:x},
   success : function(result){
   //stop loading message here
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use global ajax: {for request you don't need to show any loading image, could use option `global:false`}

```
$(document).on('ajaxStart',function(event, jqxhr, settings){
    //show loading img
})
.on('ajaxComplete',function(event, jqxhr, settings){
    //hide loading img
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Check documention you have "[complete](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)" callback

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   dataType : "json",
   ...
}).done(function(data) {
 // Stuff you want to do after ajax complete
});
```

OR

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
   // Ajax Completed
});
```